# How do you delete an image and display it at the same time?

Tags: javascript, php

This is what I currently have, and the image doesn't load. I am trying to make a Snapchat like function to display images I do not want saved

```
echo '<img src="' . $image . '">';

if (unlink($fileLo)){
    $mStat = 1;
}else {
    $mStat = 0;
}
```

And for the javascript I have this to prevent right-clicking and refreshing the page every 5 seconds

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function click (e) {
if (!e)
    e = window.event;
if ((e.type && e.type == "contextmenu") || (e.button && e.button == 2) || (e.which && e.which == 3)) {
if (window.opera)
window.alert("");
return false;
}
}

if (document.layers)
document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
document.onmousedown = click;
document.oncontextmenu = click;
</script>


<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />
```

Comment: it is impossible to delete and display, also it is impossible to prevent user from saving image

Comment: @Lashane You are right, it is impossible to prevent the user from saving the image.
It was running fine a few edits ago when the image would disappear after several seconds when it refreshes. That was what I wanted but I lost the history of the past edits.

Comment: @someGUY *"I am just making it more difficult for the user to save it"*  Why? That is a useless endeavor. It's like saying "You can only rob me if you have a high school diploma." and then feeling safe about it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Nice comparison, but what I wanted something that can be only seen once and the file gets deleted afterwards, kind of like a temporary thing.

Comment: @someGUY But, as we have said, you can't do that with a web page. The user can still save the file and the user can look into the source code to get the file name and path and your code won't actually delete the file from the web server

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a file after the page has been loaded - you can make a AJAX request to the php delete function on page load to delete the image (just after the page has been loaded) so the file won't exist no more, but anyway the image is saved to the browser cache so it's possible to get it from the client side - save from the browser cache.

Also, as the javascript is a client side, the user can manipulate it, the user can block the js code so the delete request won't be sent.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the base64 of the image in php on page load, to then delete the file in the same script.

You then simply echo the base64 inline to an image tag.

That will do so the image can be shown to the user, and at the same time be deleted from the server. All with in the same php script, with no use of ajax calls.